# How to make function calls based on split string from an array

Tags: arrays, awk

I have an working code to make function calls, but it is hardcoded. I need to make it dynamic through looping.

```
function preorder(tree, node, res,  child) {
    if (node == "")
        return
    res[res["count"]++] = node
    split(tree[node], child, ",")

    #This must be made dynamic through looping 
    #based on number of childs from the elements of the array
    preorder(tree,child[1],res)
    preorder(tree,child[2],res)
    preorder(tree,child[3],res)
}

BEGIN {
    tree["1"] = "2,3"
    tree["2"] = "4"
    tree["3"] = "5"
    tree["4"] = "6,7"
    tree["5"] = "8,9"
    tree["6"] = "10,11,12"

    preorder(tree,"1",result)
    printf "Child:\n"
    for (n = 0; n < result["count"]; n += 1)
    {
    printf "\t"
    printf result[n]" "
    printf "\n"
}
printf "\n"
    delete result

}
```

In the above code, say I have 3 comma separated values in the element 6 in the array named tree (`tree["6"] = "10,11,12"`), the preorder function must loop through it and do a self recursion for each values.

```
    preorder(tree,child[1],res)
    preorder(tree,child[2],res)
    preorder(tree,child[3],res)
```

must be made dynamic.

```
for (value in splitrecords)
    preorder(tree,child[value],res)
```

I am a beginner in AWK. Any help?

Comment: your preorder function has four arguments defined but you're passing only three!

Comment: @karakfa, declaring more function parameters than used in a function is a way to use function local variables in awk. In this case the `child` parameter is never used in calls to `preorder` function because its value is destroyed by the `split` function.

Comment: I do not think @realspirituals is an AWK beginner... unless he just had copied and pasted the code.

Comment: Yes @Jdamian, I am I just copied it from a website.

Comment: Don't mix your metaphors - trees have branches and leaves, not children. Either go with tree/branch or branch/leaf or parent/child or similar, not tree/child or parent/branch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd arg to split() is a regexp, not a string, so use regexp delimiters. This is what you want:

```
function preorder(tree, node, res,  child, i) {
    ...
    split(tree[node], child, /,/)

    for (i=1; i in child; i++) {
        preorder(tree,child[i],res)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the difference between this snippet and the one I had with `for (i in child`

Comment: The `in` operator when used on its own in a loop (`for (i in array)`) visits each element of the array in the order they are stored in a hash, NOT the order they were inserted or the order of the indices or any other useful ordering. When used as a test (`if (i in array)`) it just returns true if that index `i` exists in the array. When you have contiguous numeric indices you want to loop on in order, then, you can use `in` in a conditional context in the loop control statement (`for (i=1;i in array;i++)`) to step through the array sequentially and exit when `i` is no longer an array index.

Comment: I also made `i` function-local so it won't be changed globally by each recursive function call, when the first `preorder` returns the local `i` will have the same value it did before the child `preorder` was called.

Comment: I don't understand the question. `child` IS an array and idk what `Does this hold good` means.

Comment: your comments should go into the answer.

Comment: No, that's basic awk. Anyone who doesn't understand it almost certainly doesn't understand a lot more about awk and so should read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to get the fundamentals down instead of trying to learn them one script at a time. I'm happy to answer questions of course.

Comment: I highly recommend that book. Trying to learn awk from snippets you find online is the worst possible approach as you wont know enough yet to weed out the 90% of complete nonsense you'll come across. (e.g. in your copied example - tree/child is terrible nomenclature and you should NEVER do `printf result[n]` instead of `printf "%s",result[n]`, and you should always use `print ""` instead of `printf "\n"`, etc.). Seriously - read the book!

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote it with slight changes, there are still some things that bother me but couldn't find a better solution

```
function preorder(node, child, t, n) {
    result[c++] = node
    if(!(node in tree)) return
    n=split(tree[node], child, ",")
    for(t=1;t<=n;t++) preorder(child[t])
}

BEGIN {
    tree[1] = "2,3"
    tree[2] = "4"
    tree[3] = "5"
    tree[4] = "6,7"
    tree[5] = "8,9"
    tree[6] = "10,11,12"

    preorder(1)
    print "Child:"
    for (n=0; n<c; n++) print "\t" result[n]    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts